# How to fix Multiple user per role?

Tags: c#, .net-5

I am at this stage in my code where I need to add multiple roles per user but when it gets to the point of execution it enters an exception saying "Duplicate name"

Note, this same had been added to the system already as a sub-merchant under a merchant by invitation and signup, but now wants to be a user of the app but as a merchant through signup but this time the only change to this user account(some information from the sub merchant account like email will be retained) will be inserting a new record in the roles table with the same userid(long guid string) and new "merchant" role Id(int).

But on attempt to perform this operation, it yells a "Duplicate name", i am guessing it analyzed the payload attached to system user that consists of same email or so...

```
 var systemUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = UserIsSubMerchantObj.Email, Email = UserIsSubMerchantObj.Email, UserID = UserIsSubMerchantObj.UserId };

                    if (systemUser != null)
                    {
                        //var AddRoleUser = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(systemUser, Role.RoleName);
                        roles.Append("Merchant");

                        var AddRoleUser = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(systemUser, roles);
```

Comment: Which version of .NET Core?

Comment: this  is .Net Core 5.0

Comment: Since v5 it's just known as _.NET_ with no _"Core"_.  Thus .NET 5.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5